# Creating Java POJOs from Mongo collections

Tags: java, mongodb, pojo, generate, autocreate

I have a existing MongoDB and I need to write Java POJOs for all the collections.

Is there any tool which can auto-generate the POJOs from the mongo collections?

I am able to find tools to convert Mongo collections to JSON, but could not find a suitable way to convert the collections to Java POJOs.

Comment: There are some IDE plugins for Eclipse (JSON2JAVA) and IntelliJ (Json2Pojo).

Comment: Hi. Thanks. 
I am looking for plugins/tools to convert mongo collections to java pojos.

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 0):

using the http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

a json like:

```
{
  "type":"object",
  "working":true,
  "id":1
}
```

will produce

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;
@SerializedName("working")
@Expose
private Boolean working;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Long id;

public String getType() {
return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

public Boolean getWorking() {
return working;
}

public void setWorking(Boolean working) {
this.working = working;
}

public Long getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
this.id = id;
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses. 
Well, I am already using MongoToJSON and JSONToPOJO. 
In this , I need to do lot of changes and its taking lot of time. 
Example : When I export Mongo collections to JSON, I need to find one document which is having no null value and then I put that in the plugin: JSONToPOJO. 

I was hoping to find a tool like JPA tool in eclipse which generates all entities at once intelligently.

Comment: If nothing comes up it would be a cool thing to write this, @VishalAwasthi. If the structures aren't complicated its.